# How to unlock screensaver over ssh on ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: screensaver

I want to unlock the black screen over ssh (screensaver). I have a desktop ubuntu 21.04 and I want to log into this via ssh and unlock the screensaver.
I tried xdotool in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
xdotool type "1234"
```

and also ydotool:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
ydotool type "1234"
```

xdotool does nothing and with ydotool i get an error ( ydotool: notice: ydotoold backend unavailable (may have latency+delay issues)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  failed to open uinput device ).

How can I unlock the screensaver over an ssh connection?

Thanks

Regards David

Comment: @Nmath: Thank you very much. I hope the question is now clearer.

Comment: @Organic Marble: Thanks, yes thats the question. When I use the kill command like you write `sudo kill -9`, he tells me the help of the kill command

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I don`t have a keyboard on this pc, because i have a touchscreen. When I insert a keyboard and use ydotool as su, it works. Maybe also this solution with keyboard but without sudo could work https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool/issues/36